# Full Node Set-Up Issue: UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: iri-node, nodesharing

I'm trying to set up a full-node but I keep getting this error message:

```
11/28 [main] INFO  com.iota.iri.IRI - Welcome to IRI 1.4.1.2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\librocksdbjni2821609598978448657.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryFromJar(NativeLibraryLoader.java:78)
    at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:56)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.loadLibrary(RocksDB.java:64)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.<clinit>(RocksDB.java:35)
    at com.iota.iri.storage.rocksDB.RocksDBPersistenceProvider.<init>(RocksDBPersistenceProvider.java:28)
    at com.iota.iri.Iota.initializeTangle(Iota.java:203)
    at com.iota.iri.Iota.init(Iota.java:94)
    at com.iota.iri.IRI.main(IRI.java:86)
11/28  [Shutdown Hook] INFO  com.iota.iri.IRI - Shutting down IOTA node, please hold tight...
```

There's a github thread here: https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/issues/350

But no one found any solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not specific to iota but I've often found that `UnsatisfiedLinkError` usually means that the dll(s) are not in the location specified by `-Djava.library.path`/`PATH` property.

- Try setting the `-Djava.library.path` the the dll(s) location.
- Or put the dll(s) in a location already in `PATH`